# PhoneGap catch 'Go' pressed event for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, webview

I want to know how to catch 'Go' pressed event using PhoneGap.

I have a form with 2 input fields. How do I catch when user has pressed "Go" in keyboard. I tried butting the input fields in a `Form` and added a `onSubmit` method. And in my Js I have the method.

```
function onLoginSubmit(e){
   console.log('submit pressed');
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

But looks like the method is never called. What is the best way of doing it? 
An example would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try following code:

```
<head>
<script  language="javascript">
function show()
{
  if(window.event.keyCode == 13)
   {
     alert(window.event.keyCode);
   }
}
</script></head>
<body>
<input  type="text" name="textfields" onKeyPress="show();">
</body>
```