# submit form with enter key in textarea using knockoutjs submit binding

Tags: knockout.js, submit, enter

I want to submit my form using submit binding but it is not working. In my form i have only textarea field. How can i achieve this. When i press enter key it just comes to next line in text area but does not submit the form. I am developing my app for mobile using phonegap so enter key code 13 wont work. Here is my form.

```
<form data-bind="submit:EditQuestion" method="post" data-ajax="false">
    <textarea placeholder="Answer" data-bind="value:Answer"></textarea>
</form>
```

### Fiddle Demo

Comment: So are you saying that `event.keyCode === 13` does not work with phonegap on mobile?

Comment: This and other posts I've seen seem to go down that path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502561/phonegap-catch-go-pressed-event-for-iphone

Comment: I've got an updated fiddle but won't post my answer if it's been tested already and is failing: http://jsfiddle.net/3ux7Lj4g/3/

Comment: if you want to use enter key to trigger the form, it means the answer in textarea is always **single line**. So the question is why you use `<textarea>` instead of `<input>` (which works) ?

Comment: because it is requirement. Answer can be too long and needs to be displayed to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ENTER key truly cannot be detected from the phone, you could add a custom binding handler which monitors the `<textarea>` and then calls the `EditQuestion` function when it sees an ENTER character. Probably not the most elegant solution however.

Modify your `<textarea>` to include the new binding handler. I'm going to name it `textAreaEditQuestion`:

```
<textarea placeholder="Answer" data-bind="value:Answer, textAreaEditQuestion:Answer"></textarea>
```

And here is the custom binding handler (which polls every 100ms):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.textAreaEditQuestion = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var handle = setInterval(function () {
            var index = element.value.indexOf('\n');
            if (index !== -1) {
                // we found an ENTER key so stop monitoring
                clearInterval(handle);
                // grab the value minus the ENTER key
                var value = element.value.substr(0, index);
                // set the value in your ViewModel
                valueAccessor()(value);
                // call the EditQuestion function
                viewModel.EditQuestion();
            }
        }, 100);
    }
};
```

Comment: A couple things... (1) you have `console` misspelled as `concole` in your `EditQuestion` method, and (2) an error is getting thrown when you call `ko.validation.registerExtenders()` so it appears you need to add a reference to the knockout validation library in your fiddle.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3ux7Lj4g/5/)... Seems to work